# How does Gradle's configurations hierarchy work?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I know there are four basic configurations, compile, runtime, testCompile, and testRuntime. If I put in a dependency like this:

```
runtime group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.3'
```

This means this dependency is available under runtime *and* compile, correct? But what about testCompile and testRuntime? Is it available for these configurations as well? If I add my own configuration, do I have to specify where it exists in the hierarchy? What happens if I don't? The documentation didn't really make this clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The definition for those 4 configuration are as follow for the java plugin :

**compile**
The dependencies required to compile the production source of the project.

**runtime**
The dependencies required by the production classes at runtime. By default, also includes the compile time dependencies.

**testCompile**
The dependencies required to compile the test source of the project. By default, also includes the compiled production classes and the compile time dependencies.

**testRuntime**
The dependencies required to run the tests. By default, also includes the compile, runtime and test compile dependencies.

you can also check https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations, it has pretty graph and table:

[image]

When you declare a new configuration you can define what other configuration it extends, for example *Gradle In Action* takes the example with *Geb*, you would define new configuration as

```
configurations {
    functTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    functTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}
```

If you dont, you assume those configuration do not need to benefit from another one and its standalone, you will need to define all dependencies this configuration requires.

Comment: great answer! Is there a way to explore the configuration three with a command? (i.e. not having to rely on the documentation of each plugin). For instance the command `gradle dependencies` shows all dependencies broken down for all configurations, but doesn't show how configuration extend from each other.