# gradle configuration for powermock 1.7.4 and mockito 1.10.19

Tags: java, gradle, configuration, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to run Java tests with PowerMock version 1.7.4 and Mockito version 1.10.19, using Gradle.

PowerMock 1.7.4 has transitive dependencies on both

org.mockito » mockito-core  1.10.19 
and on
org.mockito » mockito-core  2.8.9

(See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito-common/1.7.4)

In order to NOT bring in Mockito 2.8.9, but instead have tests compile and run against Mockito 1.10.19, I have to do the following (because of various transitive dependencies within the powermock jars):

```
testCompile ("org.mockito:mockito-core:${versions.mockito}") {
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
}

testCompile ("org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito-common:${versions.powermock}") {
    exclude group: 'org.mockito', module: 'mockito-core'
}

testCompile ("org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:${versions.powermock}") {
    exclude group: 'org.mockito', module: 'mockito-core'
}

testCompile ("org.powermock:powermock-core:${versions.powermock}") {
    exclude group: 'org.mockito', module: 'mockito-core'
}

testCompile ("org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:${versions.powermock}") {
    exclude group: 'org.powermock', module: 'powermock-module-junit4-common'
}

testCompile ("org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:${versions.powermock}") {
    exclude group: 'org.powermock', module: 'powermock-core'
}

testCompile ("org.powermock:powermock-api-support:${versions.powermock}") {
    exclude group: 'org.powermock', module: 'powermock-core'
}

testCompile ("org.powermock:powermock-api-easymock:${versions.powermock}") {
    exclude group: 'org.powermock', module: 'powermock-api-support'
}

testCompile ("org.powermock:powermock-module-javaagent:${versions.powermock}") {
    exclude group: 'org.powermock', module: 'powermock-core'
}

testCompile ("org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent:${versions.powermock}") {
    exclude group: 'org.powermock', module: 'powermock-core'
}

testRuntime("org.mockito:mockito-core:${versions.mockito}") {
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
}
```

Where versions is:

```
versions = [
        'mockito': '1.10.19',
        'powermock': '1.7.4'
]
```

Surely there is a better, more concise way of doing this in Gradle, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to compact it, excluding only `mockito-core` :

```
testCompile ("org.mockito:mockito-core:${versions.mockito}") {
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
}

['powermock-api-mockito-common',
'powermock-api-mockito',
'powermock-core',
'powermock-module-junit4',
'powermock-module-junit4-common',
'powermock-api-support',
'powermock-api-easymock',
'powermock-module-javaagent',
'powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent'].each {
    testCompile ("org.powermock:${it}:${versions.powermock}") {
        exclude group: 'org.mockito', module: 'mockito-core'
    }  
}
```

Moreover the testRuntime `mockito-core` is useless as [`testRuntime` extends `testCompile`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32355321/2003986)